# Find all triples $(a, b, c)$ of real numbers such that $a + 4b + 18c =\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6}=2022$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find all triples $(a, b, c)$ of real numbers such that $$a + 3b + 18c + min(a, b, c) =\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6}=2022$$

There are three cases ( $a$ is min, or $b$ or $c$)

Case 1: $a$ is min.

We get  $$2a + 3b + 18c =\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6}=2022$$

Using Cauchy Schwarz inequality, we get $$2022^2=(2a+3b+18c)^2\le(2^2+3^2+18^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

But substituting $a^2+b^2+c^2$ we get that $$2022^2=(2a+3b+18c)^2=(2^2+3^2+18^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\implies \frac{2}{a}=\frac{3}{b}=\frac{18}{c}$$

So $$b=3a/2, c=9a\implies 2a+9a/2+18\times 9a=2022\implies a=12\implies b=18, c=108$$

But for the other two cases, I could not use the idea of equality CS inequality ( As we are not getting the equality). Any solutions?

Comment: What's the source of this question? The appearance of "$2022$" may lead some to suspect that it's from an on-going contest.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the inequality $a+3b+18c+\min(a,b,c)\le 2a+3b+18c$ holds in all cases.

Comment: Woah thankyou, I solved the problem :D